# how to securely store preloaded .crt file in android apps

Tags: java, android, security

I have an android application which uses SSL Pinning. The app has preloaded server certificate file (.crt file) in assets folder which I now need to protect from reverse engineering attacks.

As if now, when I decompile my apk using [Jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) or similar apk decompiler anybody can see and use .crt file. Any help/pointers to secure my .crt would be greatly appreciated.

P.S - Posting this question as could not find a relevant response in my search.

Comment: how about just encode with encrypt library?

Comment: @daniel any suggestions on encrypt library?

Comment: You could use Cipher for those. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography

Comment: Anyway, There is no absolutely safe method for store data. Protection method will be make cost expensive for hacking.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.Wang for the suggestion it worked.

Comment: welcome. I'm glad to you solve your problem.